# How to get inner template class to be of type of outer template class?

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, nested

My current code looks like follows: [Code here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/257764cd75c9e292)

I have a template `ClassOuter` and a nested template `ClassInnerBase`, where `TypeD` can be of any type of `TypeA, TypeB, TypeC` and no other. Furthermore, `ClassInnerDerived` should inherit from `ClassInnerBase` and implement the `virtual const int Method(int id) = 0;`.

```
template<typename TypeA, typename TypeB, typename TypeC>
class ClassOuter {
public:

    class ClassInnerBase {
    public:
        ClassInnerBase(int x) :
                m_x(x) {
        }

        virtual const int Method(int id) = 0;

    private:
        int m_x;
    };

    template<typename TypeD>
    class ClassInnerDerived : public ClassInnerBase {
    public:
        ClassInnerDerived<TypeD>(const TypeD &object, int x) :
                ClassInnerBase(x), m_object(object) {

        }

        // Implementation of ClassInnerBase::Method for type float
        template<>
        const int ClassInnerDerived<float>::Method(int id){
            return GetLookupID(id);
        }

        // Implementation of ClassInnerBase::Method for type double
        template<>
        const int ClassInnerDerived<double>::Method(int id){
            return GetLookupID(id);
        }


    private:
        TypeD m_object;
    };

    void DoSomething(const std::vector<ClassInnerBase> &inner_vec, int id);

    const int GetLookupID(int id) const{
        return lookup[id];
    }

private:
    int lookup[100];
};

template<typename TypeA, typename TypeB, typename TypeC>
void ClassOuter<TypeA, TypeB, TypeC>::DoSomething(const std::vector<ClassInnerBase> &inner_vec, int id){
    for(const auto &inner : inner_vec){
        inner.Method(id);
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<typename ClassOuter<int, double, float>::ClassInnerBase> class_base_objects;
    typename ClassOuter<int, double, float>::template ClassInnerDerived<float> class_inner_derived_object(0.2f, 1);
    class_base_objects.push_back(class_inner_derived_object);

    typename ClassOuter<int, double, float>::template DoSomething(class_base_objects, 1);
}
```

I end up getting the error:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:30:18: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class ClassOuter<TypeA, TypeB, TypeC>::ClassInnerDerived<TypeD>'
         template<>
                  ^
```

I'm quite stuck here and don't know how to resolve this error.
Additionally, are there any suggestions/comments/improvements on the implementation ifself?

Comment: You would better be better off at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for improvements on your implementation

Comment: @Rakete1111 No, Code Review is *not* a place for broken code since it is off-topic over there.  He asked on the right site.

Comment: @syb0rg I only meant the improvement bit. For the actual error OP is on the right site

Answer (score 0):

As your compiler says you cannot explicitly (fully) specialize the inner class of a template class. What you are doing is even worse as you are trying to specialize a single method from the inner class which is impossible even for non-nested template classes... What you can do is to trick the compiler by adding additional template parameter with default value to your inner class and specialize entire inner class partially. This will actually let you to test if the template parameter is of given type using sfinae mechanism (I tested as in your example if the inner template parameter is literally double or float but you can similarly test if it is one of an outer template types just as well) e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename TypeA, typename TypeB, typename TypeC>
class ClassOuter {
public:

    class ClassInnerBase {
    public:
        ClassInnerBase(int x) :
                m_x(x) {
        }

        virtual const int Method(int id) = 0;

    private:
        int m_x;
    };

    template<typename TypeD, typename = void>
    class ClassInnerDerived;

    template<typename TypeD>
    class ClassInnerDerived<TypeD, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<TypeD, float>::value || std::is_same<TypeD, double>::value> >: public ClassInnerBase {
    public:
        // Implementation of ClassInnerBase::Method for type float
        ClassInnerDerived(const TypeD &object, int x) :
                ClassInnerBase(x), m_object(object) {
        }
        const int Method(int id){
            return GetLookupID(id);
        }
    private:
        TypeD m_object;
    };

    public:

    //static void DoSomething(const std::vector<ClassInnerBase> &inner_vec, int id);

    static const int GetLookupID(int id) {
        return lookup[id];
    }

private:
    static int lookup[100];
};

template<typename TypeA, typename TypeB, typename TypeC>
int ClassOuter<TypeA, TypeB, TypeC>::lookup[100];

/*
template<typename TypeA, typename TypeB, typename TypeC>
void ClassOuter<TypeA, TypeB, TypeC>::DoSomething(const std::vector<ClassInnerBase> &inner_vec, int id){
    for(const auto &inner : inner_vec){
        inner.Method(id);
    }
}*/


int main()
{
std::vector<typename ClassOuter<int, double, float>::ClassInnerBase *> class_base_objects;
    //typename ClassOuter<int, double, float>::template ClassInnerDerived<float> class_inner_derived_object(0.2f, 1);
    class_base_objects.push_back(new ClassOuter<int, double, float>::ClassInnerDerived<float>(0.2f, 1)); //(class_inner_derived_object);

    //typename ClassOuter<int, double, float>::template DoSomething(class_base_objects, 1);
}
```

The above code probably do not actually do what you want to but I think is a good starting point...